# Loading table column names with spaces with ms sql in php

Tags: php, sql

I am using php to connect to my ms sql server. I am using php 5.3, using the microsoft database dll to connect. The problem i have is that in my database, i have tables wich there column's names have blank spaces, mean there is a table called bills whit a column named "Shipper Code" or "Shipper name"... something like that... i want to know how i can read the rows using fetch_object

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row->Code . $row->MasterId  . "</li>";
  echo "<li>". $row->Shipper Code . "</li>";   <== HERE HOW I MUST PUT SHIPPER CODE?
}
```

Do i must use () or {} or []...

thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer. I only need to use "{" and "}". Something like this

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt))
{

    echo "<li>" . $row->{"Num"} . $row->{"MasterId"}  . "</li>";
    echo "<li>". $row->{"Shipper Code"}. "</li>";
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid the usage of spaces in column or object names.  If you wish to separate the strings then use an underscore `_` instead.  This will retain the readability and ensure that the item can be accessed properly.

Other than that you can use the following:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) {
   $results[] = $row;
   echo "<li>" . $results['Code'] . $results['MasterId']  . "</li>";
   echo "<li>". $results['Shipper Code'] . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, i know i must not use blank spaces in column names. But those tables are from a migration, so i need to load those fields. How i can do that? Thats what i need to solve for the moment. Thanks again :D